# Conditional formatting - coloring a row based on whether a cell within the row matches a cell outside the range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

[image]

Wanting to apply conditional formatting to a range within a Google sheet, but the dependency is based on whether a cell within the range matches a cell outside the range.

```
    A     B     C 
1 John 
2 Bob 
3 Phil 
4 
5 
6  NZ    John  Rugby 
7  Aust  John  Soccer 
8  NZ    Bob   Tennis 
9  NZ    John  Baseball 
10 Aust  Phil  Tennis
```

Above is a simplified sheet. I have 3 unique names in `A1`, `A2` & `A3`. Below that info is a chart of people from a work group.

I want to apply conditional formatting to the chart so that all the rows containing John are shaded red, rows containing Bob are shaded blue and rows containing Phil are shaded green.

Most tutorial videos are based on the assumption that the conditional formatting required would need a formula like `=$B6="John"` with a range of `A6:C10` and shading it red.

I'm looking for something a bit more generic so the formula isn't listing specific names, rather a cell such as `A1`. So the formula might look like `=$B6=A1` with a range of `A6:C10` and a shade of red.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**red color:** `=$B6=$A$1`

**blue color:** `=$B6=$A$2`

**green color:** `=$B6=$A$3`

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks player0 for that answer! that's great. Now an additional refinement needed. Sometimes there's only 2 names at the top. When that occurs, the chart is coded by the 2 colors, and the 3rd color fills in the blank cells underneath the chart. Could a 4th formula apply to the range, where blank = no color?

Comment: you could try: `=($B6=$A$3)*($A$3<>"")`